# Circular Reference in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, reference, virtual-machine

Thanks in advance for the help.
When there is a circular reference , Node.js console.log(util.inspect(ctx)) will dump out [Circular]
e.g.

Is the circular reference something that should be avoided totally if this will cause a stackoverflow or Memory issue?

If we have a loop that contains circular references, yet we set the objects to null before exiting the
loop, shouldn't the garbage collector clean up the storage, and we should not have any
out of memory or stack overflow issues afterall?

```
    function run() {
    var obj = {}, ctx = vm.createContext({});

    obj.__ctx = ctx;
    ctx.__obj = obj;
    //console.log("before:"+util.inspect(obj));
    //console.log("before:"+util.inspect(ctx));
    vm.Script.runInContext('var x = +1;', ctx);
    console.log(util.inspect(ctx));
    console.log(util.inspect(obj));
    ctx = null;
    obj = null;


     }

     for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i += 1) {

     run();
     //sys.log(sys.inspect(process.memoryUsage()));

     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this would not cause a memory issue unless you were holding a reference to the objects outside of the scope of the function. The way it is written, both objects are eligible for garbage collection as soon as they are set to null.

The console.log() method will give the circular error only because attempting to write the object graph out would result in an infinite loop, so instead it simply replies with `[Circular]`